# Why And (&&) operator in if condition returning zero - Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm facing a if condition issue in javascript. Please have look on below code.

**1.**

```
const a = 1;
if(a && a > -1)
{ 
console.log('suceess')
} 
else
{ 
console.log('failed')
}
```

Here in if condition it is returning true.

**2.**

```
const a = 0;
if(a && a > -1)
{ 
console.log('suceess')
} 
else
{ 
console.log('failed')
}
```

Here in if condition it is returning Zero.

I'm not getting this. Can someone please explain why is it so.

Comment: why do you check for `a`? what result do you expect?

Comment: @Gereon No. I didn't get.

Comment: @NinaScholz, I'm expecting that if a = 0 , then condition should be true.

Comment: If a = 0 then in `if(a && a > -1)` the first check becomes false. It's just like having `if (false &&...` and the second part of the if isn't even checked

Comment: `0` is a falsey value and will be evaluated as false rendering the whole condition false. (`a > -1` never gets evaluated due to short-circuit evaluation)

Comment: Got it. @j08691 thanks.

Comment: @phuzi , Thanks now i got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Javascript 0 is considered a "falsy" value, which mean il will be evaluate to false when used in a condition like `if (0) {}`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy for more information about falsy values.

Comment: But here a is defined and a > -1 that is also true, Then why it is returning zero.?

Comment: `if (a)` doesn't check if `a` is defined... It checks whether the value referenced by `a` is truthy and, unfortunately, `0` is falsy so gets evaluated as false.

Comment: a is defined but is equal to 0 which will evaluate to false, so 
if(0 && 0 > -1)
will become
if(false && true)
which will evaluate to false

Comment: Is there any solution, how should I do my expected thing ?

Comment: what are you trying to check? That a is not empty and > -1 ?

Comment: It's yielding zero because of how the && operator works.  If the first operand is falsy, that's what it yields.  So (undefined && true) returns undefined, (0 && true) returns zero, (false && true) returns false.

Comment: @ChristopheLeBesnerais got the solution. I was trying to check a property of object if its exist and greater than -1 then assign from a another object esle assign a constant value. And I have found that we can use IN operator to check the property exist or not. Do you have any better idea about it ?

Comment: if you want to check that a is not null and not undefined you can use if (a != null)